# Excel VBA Regex replace loses one character

Tags: regex, excel, vba

The below code matches and replaces, but the digit next to the capture group is consumed. Where am I going wrong?

```
Sub test()
    Dim regex As Object 'Regexp object.
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp") 'Regexp object.
    Dim strPattern As String: strPattern = "\d(AM|PM)" 'Declare regex pattern.
    Dim strReplace As String 'Placeholder string for replace operation.
    Dim target As String

    target = "1:05PM"

    strReplace = " $1"

    With regex
        .Global = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = strPattern
    End With

    If regex.test(target) Then
        Debug.Print regex.Replace(target, strReplace)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Output:**

```
1:0 PM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have an un-captured \d in your regex. Try putting () around the `\d` i.e. `(\d)(AM|PM)`.

You also need to change strReplace to `"$1 $2"`

Comment: See my edit. That is where the space is coming from.

Comment: See my revised edit. I'm assuming your desired output is 1:05 PM

Comment: Yep, that one did it. Thanks!